# why am I not able to convert string type column to date format in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a column which is in the "20130623" format. I am trying to convert it into dd-mm-YYYY. I have seen various post online including here. But I only got one solution as below

```
from datetime import datetime
df = df2.withColumn("col_name", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int("col_name")).strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
```

However, it throws an error that the input should be `int type`, `not the string type`. I tried to convert with the help of `int()` function. But even that doesn't seem to be helping.

below is the error that I see when converting

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'col_name'
```

I am not sure if it is taking the col_name as string, or its value as string.
Please suggest, how can I do this, or the best way to get the required output

Note: I cannot use pandas in my environment.

thank you.

Comment: `df.withColumn("date", to_date("date_str", format="yyyyMMdd"))` where `from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date`

Comment: `withColumn` should strictly use Spark types. You can not use python datetime there.

Comment: ok, Thank you for yur help, it is working. But as I said, the final output should be dd-mm-yyyy. "to_date()" doesn't seem to do that. I undertand that the string which I gave here is having "YYYY" first. But now, since to_date has converted to date format, is there any way to get "dd-mm-yyyy"?

Comment: Please see example on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html

Comment: Add one more line `df = df.withColumn("date_ddMMyyyy", F.date_format("date", format="dd-MM-yyyy"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[withColumn()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html) should use Spark types. You can not use python datetime there.

First parse string to date using [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) and then format date to string using [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["20130623"]], schema=["date_str"])

df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("date_str", format="yyyyMMdd"))
df = df.withColumn("date_ddMMyyyy", F.date_format("date", format="dd-MM-yyyy"))

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
|date_str|date      |date_ddMMyyyy|
+--------+----------+-------------+
|20130623|2013-06-23|23-06-2013   |
+--------+----------+-------------+

root
 |-- date_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- date_ddMMyyyy: string (nullable = true)
```

Whatever you see as output `2013-06-23` in `date` column is actually default to_string() representation of date.